# How do I set headers the react-dom/server renderToString passes to graphql server?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, server-side-rendering, react-server

I have a webserver which receives the client's IP from the load balancer via the `X-Forwarded-For` header, but does not forward it to the GraphQL server, making debugging more difficult.

Is it possible to turn this on, or would it require a patch to react-dom/server? How have others solved the problem of gathering contextual data in the graphql server request logs when they are triggered by a server-side-renderer?

Comment: You need tell more about which Load Balancer? Also does the LB interact directly with GraphQL server or how? This is a infrastructure dependent question and should include the infra details as well

Comment: @TarunLalwani the LB interacts with the GraphQL server through the webserver’s server side renderer, which uses the react/dom-server library

Comment: Which LB? AWS or something else. Also if you take LB out of picture the IP can be seen correctly?

Comment: I don't think the LB is in the picture, it just passes an X-Forwarded-For header which I know how to extract and would like to pass to `react-dom/server` to forward to the database.

Comment: I think now I get it, you use a graphql-client on server which makes the IP come as your server ip for every request and you want to actually see the client ip which triggered the server renderer. Right?

Comment: Yup! I see an internal webserver IP in my graphql logs and no user agent header where I would like to see some headers that would allow me to at least tie the two log statements together.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible straight away, but if you provide a ready to use environment using docker-compose or something, I might be able to dig further and help you out. Else setting up the whole environment to reproduce the condition may take too much time for me

Comment: It’s a k8s environment with svc local DNS touting. Whatever the library sends the GraphQL server is what it gets in headers — k8s does not any headers on application layer, I don’t think? Can test and verify tomorrow.

Comment: A repo with `deploy.sh` will also work even if it is a `k8s`, I have a local `k8s` minikube with me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171083/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-andrey-fedorov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll dig into the source shortly to verify, but it doesn't seem like this is actually possible at this time.